# Array Objects without Quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I have to change in the code below to receive an array without quotes for each element (best is: if they got commas)

What I need:

```
myData = [
            {id:0,
            label:"First",
            color:"#ffffff",
            value:"30"},

            {id:1,
            label:"Second",
            color:"#000000",
            value:"70.0000000000"}
        ]
```

what i get:

```
myData = [
            "{id:0,
            label:"First",
            color:"red",
            value:"30"}"

            "{id:1.00000,
            label:"Second",
            color:"blue",
            value:"70.0000000000"}"
        ]
```

The code that create what I get:

```
function AddRowToTable(id, name, desc, value, color) {
  arr.push('{id:' + id + ', label:"' + name + '", color:"'+ color + '", value:"' + value + '"}');
}
```

What can I change to remove the "" outside of the {} - inside they are fine.

To understand the whole story: [Link to other Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737147/how-to-add-a-array-to-a-javascript-variable/33737414?noredirect=1#comment55272548_33737414)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Push an object to your array, not a string

Comment: I don't see any [semicolon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon) in your code: did you mean [quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing a sting to the array, not an object, you need the following

```
function AddRowToTable(id, name, desc, value, color) {
      arr.push({id: id, label: name , color: color, value: value});
}
```

Notice that I have removed the quotes and am not concatenating using `+`. However what is `arr` in your function? Is it a variable outside the function? Ahem..

```
var arr = [];

function AddRowToTable(id, name, desc, value, color) {
          arr.push({id: id, label: name , color: color, value: value});
}

AddRowToTable(1, 'mike sav', 'what is this?', 'red', '10000');
```

Also why are you passing `desc` as an argument but not using it?

Comment: hi Mike its just a part of the whole code - when you have a look on my post - the last link brings you to another discussion where the whole code is in...

about the desc argument - finaly i need more  arguments but to make it easier to read i deleted most of them in the question.

i try to push now as an object...

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to:

```
function AddRowToTable(id, name, desc, value, color) {
  arr.push({id: id, label: name, color: color, value: value});
}
```

This way, you are pushing an object (that's what you want!) instead of a string.